# Not able to start hybris in debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, e-commerce, eclipse-kepler, sap-commerce-cloud

When tying to start Hybris in debug mode using Eclipse Kepler showing error

```
“Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect”
```

Even I  tried by changing the default port also

```
tomcat.debugjavaoptions=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n
```

but showing the same error. Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: which OS you are using? and how and where you are trying to debug mode? generally starting hybris server with -debug flag will do work for you

Comment: I'm using Hybris-4.7 and OS Windows-8

Comment: The `debug` (not `-debug`) will not always work - see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change first debug port using below property

```
tomcat.debug.port=<please provide port which is free>
```

in `local.properties` file then start server using

> hybrisserver.bat debug

Comment: @MattClark This looks like an answer to me, albeit badly formatted. It says "Change this setting by doing this", with an implied "and that will fix it".

Answer (score 2):

1. Place **tomcat.debug.port=** into local.properties.
2. Place **tomcat.debugjavaoptions=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=port_number>,suspend=n -Xverify:none -DforceANSI=true** into local.properties
3. Go to eclipse **Debug Configuration**, set port same as in local.properties.
4. In commons tab check Debug option
5. Place **tomcat.enable.debug=true** into catalina.properties
6. Then start server hybrisserver.bat debug (For Windows OS).

Comment: `Place tomcat.enable.debug=true` is not necessary...if you are running with `debug` command on server startup.

Answer (score 1):

```
tomcat.debugjavaoptions=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=50021,suspend=n -Xverify:none -DforceANSI=true
```

1. Close Eclipse/intelliJ
2. Change port
3. `ant all & hybrisserverstart.bat debug`

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Go to local.properties in config folder and add the following lines:

```
tomcat.debug.port=8001
tomcat.debugjavaoptions=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8001,suspend=n -Xverify:none -DforceANSI=true
```

Make sure the port you use (here 8001) is free.

Step 2: Go to `\hybris\bin\platform\tomcat\conf\catalina.properties` and add:

```
tomcat.enable.debug=true
```

Step 3: `ant all`
Step 4: `hybrisserver.bat debug`

Personally tried and tested, works fine!

Answer (score 0):

which version of hybris are you using?
How do you currently start hybris? Is hybris and eclipse on the same machine? do you have admin privileges?

i am using hybris 3.1 with eclipse-helios.

First i start hybris **without** eclipse in debugmode: using ...\platform\tomcat-6\bin\debug.bat at commandline.

After that i start debugging by attaching the eclipse-debugger to that debugmode-running hybris instance using a eclipse debug configuration "remote java application" with connection Properties: host=localhost, port=8000.

Answer (score 0):

you should run your hybris server with -debug option in console and by default connect debugger to port 9000 . that worked with me

Answer (score 0):

Go to ...\hybris\bin\platform and run hybrisserver.bat debug in windows
or hybrisserver.sh in unix

This will start the hybris server in debug mode

During server start up, you can see a line that says hybris server starting in debug mode at the very start.

Answer (score 0):

Running `hybris\bin\platform\hybrisserver.bat debug` should start your server ready to debug but all it actually does is use the configuration in `hybris\bin\platform\tomcat\conf\wrapper-debug.conf`. So you need to check that file and add the following lines if they are missing:

```
wrapper.java.additional.34=-Xdebug
wrapper.java.additional.35=-Xnoagent
wrapper.java.additional.36=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n
```

Note the numbers (e.g. 34, 35, 36) need to be adapted according to which additional lines you already have in your .conf file.

Start `hybrisserver.bat debug` and wait till it's fully started. Then you can connect on port 80 (set in IntellJ under Run -> Edit Configurations -> Remote...)

Answer (score 0):

Open file `hybris\bin\platform\tomcat\conf\wrapper-debug.conf` and go to the following line:

```
wrapper.java.additional.36=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n
```

In that change port number 8000 to 8001.